# how can select all columns and one of them without rebeating

Tags: sql-server

[image]

[image]

When I do

```
select * , empname as managerName
```

I want all data then just `managerName`

Comment: clarify your question dude

Comment: it is yours @Beth

Comment: what is yours @Sean Lange

Comment: Please post query and result as text and not as an external screen shot (you can show results as text in Management Studio using Query -> Results To), if you can do it also for the tables the better.

Comment: Try to be more clear with your question. Also it's better to have text rather than image screenshots as they can copy and pasted and worked with much easier.

Comment: `select employees.*,departments.*,e.empname managerName
from employees,employees e, departments
where departments.deptid=employees.deptid
and e.empid=departments.managerid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list the employees and the name of each employee's department manager, you will need to join the Employee table twice.  One way to do this is:

```
Select Employees.*
   , Departments.*
   , Managers.EmployeeName as ManagerName
From Employees
Inner Join Departments on departments.DeptID = employees.DeptID
Inner Join Employees managers on managers.EmpId = departments.ManagerID
```

Comment: thanks, that's how i solved
by where syntax 
====================================================
select employees.*,departments.*,e.empname managerName
from employees,employees e, departments
where departments.deptid=employees.deptid
and
    e.empid=departments.managerid

Comment: but in both there is two columns (deptid), and 
i want to display only one

Comment: To list specific fields, you will need to list them instead of using `Departments.*` - just replace it with the actual fields you want to see. 
 For example: `departments.deptname, departments.comId`.  You should do the same with `Employees.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact you need to put more through into forming your question..

If all you are trying to do is find the manager.. you just need to join the department back to the employee using the manager id.. something like this

```
select 
e.empid
,e.empname
,e.jobtitle
,e.salary
,d.deptname
,m.empname as manager_name

from employee e

    inner join departments d
        on d.deptid = e.deptid

    left join employee m
        on m.empid = d.managerid
```